# SSMS: How to sort objects by date?

Tags: sql-server-2000, ssms

i created a stored procedure recently, and i would like to sort the list of stored procedures by date.

12 years ago this was easy:
[image]

What is the preferred way to accomplish this in SQL Server Management Studio?
[image]

Bonus: How to sort by owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: It's not possible.

### **Upate**: Possible

Sometime in the intervening 9 years since i first asked this question, SSMS added the feature that was present c. 2000: **Object Explorer Details**:

[image]

And you get the functionality of a user interface that was created 25 years ago:

[image]

I understand **why** didn't want to let see items in a folder: it's so much work. It's easier to make the user's suffer everyday, rather than the developers once.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to right-click the database that you are interested in and select the New Query button in the toolbar. In the Query window, insert the following TSQL:

```
SELECT type, type_desc, name, create_date, modify_date
FROM sys.objects
GO
```

This gives you system objects as well so you'll have to filter it accordingly. You could always change the select statement to "SELECT *" to get a quick view of the other columns available.

I wanted to give you the starting point and you can go where you want with it.

Comment: That doesn't really affect the SSMS UI.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if it's preferred or not but, i guess you can insert the result table into a temptable and write a select query for that table with the order by.

downside, you have to write the column names and types every time.

`declare @temptable table(Name nvarchar(50),Owner nvarchar(50),Type nvarchar(50),CreateDate DateTime)`
`insert into @temptable your_procedure`
`select * from @temptable order by CreateDate desc`

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, you can go to "Object Explorer Details" (F7 in 2008, menu in 2005/2008)

You have a choice of details view, you can see the create date.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646011.aspx)

I suspect it isn't what you want though... and I don't know it it works with SQL Server 2000